# Translating a word problem in order to use Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was solving a Lagrange multipliers exercises that goes as follows:

> Your firm has been asked to design a storage tank for liquid petroleum gas. The customer’s specifications call for a cylindrical tank with hemispherical ends, and the tank is to hold $8000 m^3$ of gas. The customer also wants to use the smallest amount of material possible in building the tank. What radius and height do you recommend for the cylindrical portion of the tank?

When I was solving it I took $2\pi rh$ as the surface area of the cylinder as they mentioned "**cylindrical portion of the tank**" while they took $4\pi r^2+2\pi rh$ which is the cylinder with the 2 hemispheres, how are the 2 hemispheres considered part of the cylinder?
In my understanding a cylinder is any repeating curve, here the hemispheres don't have the same curve as the rest so how are they part of the cylinder?

Note: I do realize that the volume of $8000 m^3$ would include the 2 hemispheres hence to use our constraint right we would need the whole surface including them but my issue is that the wording seems wrong to me and I need help in clarification.

Comment: You need to solve the entire problem _before_ you can determine what the optimal cylindrical measurements are.

Comment: What am I asking about is in the setup phase, nothing about the end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total volume and total surface area of the entire tank are determined by the dimensions of the cylindrical part, because the hemispheres have radius equal to the radius of the cylindrical section. So you write down the volume and surface area in terms of $r$ and $h$ and then solve for the optimal values of $r$ and $h$ using Lagrange multipliers.

You got caught up on the phrase "cylindrical portion of the tank", but you need to read the entire sentence: "what radius and height do you recommend for the cylindrical portion of the tank?". Specifically when reading this sentence you need to realize that your recommendation for the radius will impact the size of the hemispherical parts of the tank as well.

Comment: Thank you, all clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about what a cylinder means, but here what they mean is that the tank consists of a cylinder plus two hemispherical ends (bulging outwards not inwards!)

Comment: And according to what you are saying I can't see how "cylindrical **part**" would include the hemispheres, I guess I will have to take it as it is and go.

Comment: It doesn't include the caps but it determines their radius. The variables are $r$ and $h$ as you say, the constraints is the volume of the cylinder plus the two hemisphere as you say, and you've got to minimise the suface area of the cylinder plus the two hemispheres. I think the person who set this thinks we can all picture one of these gas tanks, and has described it a bit casually.

Answer (score 0):

The tank holding $8000$ ${\rm m}^3$, and having the worldwide smallest surface, is a spherical tank of volume $8000 \ {\rm m}^3$. This spherical tank is also an admissible tank according to the order of the customer. Its cylindrical height $h$ is then $=0$, and $r=10\bigl(6/\pi)^{1/3}$ m.